# No option to disable prefetching in BIOS

Tags: intel, bios, prefetch, msr

I have been trying to disable prefetching in my laptop. After many attempts, I realized intel stopped disclosing information on how to disable prefetching from nehalem architecture.
Even if I try to modify the MSR, it always gives an error saying that i have no permission to write. Then I found it can disabled using BIOS. But, in my BIOS i have no option to disable prefetching. I have a DELL laptop and my BIOS version is 1.2.7.

Can anyone tell me what to do to disable prefetching in my laptop?
I am using Dell Inspiron 5559.

Comment: Please, provide exact model of your laptop, so ppl may help you.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 5559.